# .htaccess for cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am runing a site wishberry.in on cakephp framework. I had some dirty URLs previously and now i want them to cleanup through .htaccess

I original url was wishberry.in/createwishlist3 and i want to change that to wishberry.in/brands with a 301 redirect.

The reason for using 301 is, if someone type wishberry.in/createwishlist3, the page will take them to /brands automatically.

Can anyone help me out what to write in my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with routes in CakePHP rather than the .htaccess file. See http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2009/11/02/cakephp-s-routing-explained for more details.

Comment: hey..great reply..I just have to add an extra line in my router.php file in order to get whats required. But your answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^createwishlist3$ /brands [R=301,L,NC]
```

Hope this helps.